# Make Bases (shape squares) - Multiple sizes - Diagonal placement

Tags: netlogo

[image]

I want to make diagonal bases (Perfet square), but it only work until size 2 more then 2 i start to lose the squares.

My code is:

```
to setup-patches       
          set-patch-size 15

          ask patches[
          if (distancexy 20 20) < base-size [set pcolor yellow]
          if (distancexy -20 -20) < base-size [set pcolor yellow]

          if (distancexy -20 20) < base-size [set pcolor pink]
          if (distancexy 20 -20) < base-size [set pcolor pink]
          ]       
    end
```

Please check the picture to see what i am talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Look at two examples in the Models Library: Moore and Von Neumann, and Neighborhoods Example.  You want the box (Moore) neighborhood, and you should use `at-points` to get it.  However, sticking close to your coded setup, you can also try this:

```
to-report linf [#p1 #p2]
  let _xdist abs ([pxcor] of #p1 - [pxcor] of #p2)
  let _ydist abs ([pycor] of #p1 - [pycor] of #p2)
  report max (list _xdist _ydist)
end

to setup-patches [base-size]
  clear-all
  set-patch-size 15
  let diag1 (patch-set patch 20 20 patch -20 -20)
  ask diag1 [ask patches with [linf self myself < base-size] [set pcolor yellow]]
  let diag2 (patch-set patch -20 20 patch 20 -20)
  ask diag2 [ask patches with [linf self myself < base-size] [set pcolor pink]]
end
```